# How to execute command line tools with projects built with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

Running a Java application built with Gradle requires adding to the classpath a directory for each individual library, as it stores them in individual directories.

Therefore, when you look at the command to launch the application in IntelliJ you can easily see a whole screen filled with classpath dependencies.

This is fine for IntelliJ because it can figure them out automatically, but I want to be able to run my command line tool in the terminal, writing arguments there instead of editing my run configuration each time I want to change anything. How can I do so without pasting a whole screen of machine-specific JAR dependencies from the IDE?

Is it possible to do it in a development environment without creating a giant JAR file bundling all the libraries?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you would like to run your jar from command line, and optionally provide command line arguments for your program without the need for providing the correct arguments for the JVM?

Comment: I don't mind if it runs from a JAR or from class files. I want a one-liner that allows me to invoke the program.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [JavaExec task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html). You can create a custom task as such:

```
task customRun(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "fully.qualified.name.of.your.main"
    args = ["100", "1000" ...] // the command line options for your tool
    jvmArgs = [ ... ] // additional JVM args you might need
}
```

Then you can invoke it using `gradle customRun`. If you want to be able to provide the command line arguments, I would suggest using gradle properties:

```
gradle -PcustomRunArgs="100 1000" customRun
```

and modifying the task to grab the arguments:

```
task ... {
   ...
   if (project.hasProperty('customRunArgs')) { 
        args =  customRunArgs.split(' ')
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: It does not handle arguments with spaces. You would need a parser for that. It's too cumbersome without a wrapper script, it also clutters the output with plenty of gradle stuff, but it's still better than copypasting from an IDE.

Comment: To reduce the gradle verbosity, use switch `-q`. To support command line options with spaces, take a look at [CliBuilder](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ch/2009/09/groovy-goodness-parsing-commandline.html)